# Load optimized file requireJS

Tags: requirejs

I'm new in the use of RequireJS, so I please be patience with me.
I' developing a JS application, using AMD styles/require.js/backbone... that have two versions:
 1. Development version
 2. Optimized version using r.js in build process

The problem is in two files:
**ObjA.js**

```
define(function() {
var ObjA = {
    a: "A"
};
return ObjA;
```

});

**ObjB.js**

```
define(function() {
    var ObjB = {        
        "B": "B",
        "B.A": "B.A",
    };
    return ObjB;
});
```

The problem is that after the optimized process I create a new "concate" file with the two files, so I'm finishing with a file like:

OptimizedFile.js

```
define(function() {
    var ObjA = {
        a: "A"
    };
    return ObjA;
});
define(function() {
    var ObjB = {        
        "B": "B",
        "B.A": "B.A",
    };
    return ObjB;
});
```

Then I try to load the optimized file like:

```
if (true) {

require(["src/Objects/OptimizedFile"], function (data) {
        onload(data);
    });
}
```

The problem is that only the first object is returned, I'm guessing because of the first 'return'.
Is there a way to get the both objects using require.js and the optimized version of the file?
Or I'm trying to do something that is not possible?
I'm doing this because this optimized file is loaded only by request, only if a condition is true, that is the reason I'm not including the file in the build process.
Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't simply concatenate anonymous module files together, as they have no module name associated with them (and therefore cannot be resolved correctly by other `require()` and `define()` calls).

You will either need to do a standard RequireJS build - http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html (which will insert the module names based on the module's file path), or hard-code a module name into your modules. But hard-coding module names is not considered a best practice.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, this is what I was missing, this gave me some direction of solving the problem.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you did?  I have a main-built.js but all my modules are looking / loading the files from the filesystem instead of just from main.